# Getting XML Data of parent attributes into tables using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I need to get data from xml file into html table using javascript .

I have gone through W3School example http://www.w3schools.com/xml/tryit.asp?filename=tryxml_display_table

In my xml file child and parent attributes may be same but i want to display only parent attributes

```
<resource>
  <parent>
     <item>item1</item>
     <attribute>
       <item>subitem</item>
     </attribute>
       <item>subitem</item>
    <description>
    </description>
  </parent>
</resource>
```

In the above example i have two item tags, one is parent and others are subitems.
I just want to get parent  tag values

Here my html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
table,th,td {
  border : 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th,td {
  padding: 5px;
}
</style>
<body onload="loadXMLDoc();">


<br><br>
<table id="demo"></table>

<script>
function loadXMLDoc() {
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      myFunction(this);
    }
  };
  xmlhttp.open("GET", "newXMLfile.xml", true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
function myFunction(xml) {
  var i;
  var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
  var table="<tr><th>Name</th></tr>";
  var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("parent");
  for (i = 0; i <x.length; i++) {
    table += "<tr><td>" +
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("item")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "</td>";
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = table;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

But Here i am getting only subitem tag values .

Comment: What result do you need? <tr><th>Name</th></tr><tr><td><attribute>
       <item>subitem</item>
     </attribute></td>?

Comment: Want to print only parent attribute values  <name>value1</name>

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the `text` of the `<item>` after `<attribute>` isn't a `subitem`. Its `item`.

If you need just the `<item>`s within the `<parent>` excluding the ones within `<attribute>`:

1. Remove the `childNodes[0]` from your `getByTagName()`. It prints the first child of all the `<item>` tags within `<parent>`.
2. Add a simple check to see if the `parentNode` of the `<item>` is `<parent>`. Then print them.

Something like:

```
//Get every <item> within <parent>
var item = x[i].getElementsByTagName('item');
//for each item
for(... ){
  if(item[i].parentNode.name == "parent"){
    table += "<tr><td>" +
    item[i].nodeValue +
    "</td>";
  }
}
```

I'm not entirely sure how about `parentNode.name`. It's just an idea.

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode(v=vs.110).aspx) is the MSDN doc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and let me check once

Comment: Getting null values

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you right, try next code.

```js
var testXML=`<resource>
  <parent>
     <item>item1</item>
     <attribute>
       <item>attribute subitem</item>
     </attribute>
       <item> subitem</item>
    <description>
    </description>
  </parent>
</resource>`;

function myFunction(xml) {
  var table="<tr><th>Name</th></tr>";
  var parentNodes = $(xml).find("parent");
  for (var i = 0; i <parentNodes.length; i++) {
    table += "<tr><td>" +
    $(parentNodes[i]).find("attribute item").text() +
    "</td>";
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = table;
}

myFunction(testXML);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="demo"></table>
```